# How to register a python script with mac OSX as a web browser

Tags: python, macos, browser, registration

I have a python script that accepts URLs and displays them and I want to register it with the operation system (mac OS El Captain/Sierra), so that the script shows up in the list of possible Default web browser (in the *General* pane of the *System Preferences*).

I assume I have to turn the script into an app (e.g. via [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus)) and then modify the application bundle's `Info.plist` file or another config file. But what key do I have to set? And how does this the *register*n with the system?

*Note:* I do *not* want to register the script for a new URI protocol, just add the script to the possible Default browsers which handle HTTP, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Platypus itself can do this! In the main Settings window

[image]

select **Accepts Dropped Items**. Then press the newly appearing **Settings** Button and in the **Drop Settings** dialog

[image]

check **Register as URI scheme handler** and add the desired URI scheme(s). Run the generated app at least once and then it should appear in the list of possible Default web browsers.

Comment: What do I use for URI scheme? I just want it to be default browser for all http and https links. I tried entering `http` and `https` as schemes. But after running the generated app, it still does not show up as a possible default browser (on Ventura.)
Thanks

Comment: @Dan I've just checekd I have set the URISchemes `http` and `file`. However I am on Catalina, maybe this has changed in newer OSes.